# What happened if disable imports of .so file

Tags: android, import, .so

I am just curious about if I edit and disable a .so file imports(strlen,malloc,strcmp,etc) after that I execute the library then what happening? What should I expect!

I am expecting which imports I disable that functions are not work .

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you modified a library and called it from your application?

Comment: I am just tried to block the functions offsets with hex editor,but i am called them but i think the functions are working:(